# How to pull Instagram image caption text using the Instagram API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I'm using the Instagram api to build a site in Ruby on Rails.
I can't seem to figure out how to pull caption text with any of the images, and it doesn't seem to state how to do this anywhere in the documentation.  Is it possible using the api or do I have to use something else?

I've attached 2 very simple code snippets to illustrate my problem below

Ruby:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    def index
        @instagram = Instagram.tag_recent_media("blablabla", {:count => 50})
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div class = "tagged-images-container-position">
    <% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
            <%= instagram.caption.text %> <!-- THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK -->
            <%= instagram.user.username %> 
            <%= image_tag(instagram.images.standard_resolution.url, class: "tagged-images") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Is that the ruby instagram library? Maybe you can post here: https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem. I use C# and pars the response manually and can get the caption text no problem. I do have cases where caption is null, so getting .text is impossible. So I just check for null first)

Comment: that was actually the problem.  Thanks Sebastien!  I simply had to check if the caption existed first.

Comment: I put it as an answer then! Groovy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the caption text for null before going for that text propoerty. I found that sometimes it pops up as null.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, check the entire caption to see if it is nil, before digging down to caption.text

This technique has been working for me:

```
if instagram.caption
  caption = instagram.caption.text
else
  caption = "Oops, no caption."
end
```